# How to add AVAudioUnitEQ effects on AVPlayer

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, avaudioengine, equalizer

I am trying achive to add equalizer effects on `AVPlayer`. Basically need reverb and frequency band change of audio sound on Video Playback.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController  {
    
    let engine = AVAudioEngine()
    let reverb = AVAudioUnitReverb()
    var sourceFile: AVAudioFile!
    var format: AVAudioFormat!
   
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupAudioEngine()
    }
    
    func setupAudioEngine() {
        do {
            let sourceFileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "videosong", withExtension: "mp4")!
            sourceFile = try AVAudioFile(forReading: sourceFileURL)
            format = sourceFile.processingFormat
        } catch {
            fatalError("could not open source audio file, \(error)")
        }
        let player = AVAudioPlayerNode()
        engine.attach(player)
        engine.attach(reverb)
        // set desired reverb parameters
        reverb.loadFactoryPreset(.mediumHall)
        reverb.wetDryMix = 70
        
        // make connections
        engine.connect(player, to: reverb, format: format)
        engine.connect(reverb, to: engine.mainMixerNode, format: format)
        
        // schedule source file
        player.scheduleFile(sourceFile, at: nil)
        do {
            try engine.start()
            player.play()
        } catch {
            fatalError("could not start engine, \(error)")
        }
      //  SaveFile()
    }
}
```

I am using Video file in `mp4` format. and i need to achieve reverb effect on video playback.
How we can use `AVPlayer` as input node are any other way ? Please Help me in this.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show what you have already tried as a [example]. See also [ask].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @koen any idea to get effects on AVPlayer ?

Comment: @VikasVerma no, sorry.

Comment: As far as I know, AVPlayer isn't compatible with audio effects like reverb and equalizer. If anyone finds a way to use those effects on AVPlayer, I would like to know.

Comment: @ThorstenStark, not found any way with AVPlayer. We can replace audio with effects in sources video file.

Comment: @VikasVerma If you still need help, pls check the the example from Apple: https://github.com/robovm/apple-ios-samples/tree/master/AudioTapProcessor